# accelerometer data not correct, delayed for few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am creating a very simple game using Swift and SpriteKit and I am moving a ball on the screen using the accelerometer data (acceleration x,y).

I would say the code works fine but I have noticed that sometimes (often right when I open the app) the accelerometer data is not correct and delayed for few seconds.

Why is that happening?

I am using the following code to read the accelerometer data:

```
if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:{
            data, error in
            self.accX = CGFloat(data.acceleration.x)
            self.accY = CGFloat(data.acceleration.y)
        })
}
```

And the function update to apply some impulse to the ball:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    var impulse = CGVectorMake(accX, accY)
    var obj = childNodeWithName("ball") as SKSpriteNode
    obj.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulse)
}
```

Am i missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's the accelerometer data, rather than the physics engine trying to play catch-up due to "missed frames"? In any case it may be a good idea to stop accelerometer when the app enters background, and restart it when the app enters foreground. This should also bring up a pause screen so that user has time to prepare for the game to continue.

Comment: That's a good point actually. I agree with your "engine trying to play catch-up due to misses frames". That is the feeling when I have the problem. I will try to stop and restart the accelerometer as you said. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given priority to both functions and the issue seems fixed.

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // do some task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // code with priority
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With any accelerometer data, it is a good idea to run it through a filter to smooth out any irregular spikes.  Here is my favorite:

```
double filteredAcceleration[3];
memset(filteredAcceleration, 0, sizeof(filteredAcceleration));
CMAccelerometerData *newestAccel = motionManager.accelerometerData;
filteredAcceleration[0] = (filteredAcceleration[0]*(1.0-alpha)) + (newestAccel.acceleration.x*alpha);
filteredAcceleration[1] = (filteredAcceleration[1]*(1.0-alpha)) + (newestAccel.acceleration.y*alpha);
filteredAcceleration[2] = (filteredAcceleration[2]*(1.0-alpha)) + (newestAccel.acceleration.z*alpha);
```

alpha can be any value from 0 to 1.  The closer to 1 the more responsive it will be, the closer to zero the more smooth it will be.  My favorite value on the iPhone is 0.2  It is a good compromise for smooth yet responsive for a game like doodle jump, or possibly moving a ball around.

I don't know why the accelerometer data is incorrect/delayed on startup, my guess would be that the hardware has to wake up and calibrate itself, but regardless of the why, if you implement a filter, it will smooth out these irregularities, and they won't be nearly as noticeable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I don't believe it's a problem of smoothing the spikes but I will definitely need this later!